# can i declare a global variable outside the class in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var array= []



class Body extends Component {

state= {
 input: '',
 oprStatus: false,
 check: false,
 count: 0,
 oprArray: null
} }
```

now as i know that i cant update the 'oprArray' array inside the state by using push 
so what i was thinking that what if i declare a variable outside the class and update that array and then update the 'oprArray' inside state

```
array.push(2);
this.setState({
 oprArray: array
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't solve the problem, because you'd still be mutating state rather than setting new state. Once you've set `oprArray: array` in your state the first time, the state and the global `array` variable are both pointing to the same array. The next time, that `push` is modifying state directly — which is a no-no with React state.

To add a new item into your `oprArray`, you do it like this:

```
this.setState(({oprArray}) => ({oprArray: [...oprArray, 2]}));
```

That:

1. Uses the callback form of `setState`, which is necessary when you're modifying state (a new `oprArray` with the new entry, `2`) based on existing state (the previous contents of `oprArray`).
2. Creates a *new* array with the additional item, via spread notation.

Live Example:

```js
const {Component} = React;

class Body extends Component {
    state = {
     input: '',
     oprStatus: false,
     check: false,
     count: 0,
     oprArray: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // Since your state starts with `null`, I assume you receive initial data
        // via ajax or similar; emulated here with a timeout
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({oprArray: [0, 1]}); // Initial data isn't based on existing state
            // Now set up getting more data later
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Additional data
                this.setState(({oprArray}) => ({oprArray: [...oprArray, 2]}));
            }, 800);
        }, 800);
    }

    render() {
        const {oprArray} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>oprArray: {oprArray ? oprArray.join(", ") : "(none)"}</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Body />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```